# WampServer - MySQL 5.0.96 shows up as MySQL 5.0.51a

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp, wampserver, mysql5

I downgraded my WampServer MySQL version from 5.6.12 to 5.0.96 to match my live server's version. When I look at my phpinfo page, it shows that I'm using version 5.0.51a and phpMyAdmin shows it the same too. Where in the configuration files do I change which version number to use?

PS: I'm running Apache 2.0.63 and PHP 5.2.11.

**Edit:** SELECT version(); shows it being 5.0.96-community.

Comment: just a suggestion: If your live server environment is Linux (which is probably true), use a VM (VirtualBox or VMWare Player) on your local machine for development, your development environment will be easier to match that way.

Comment: @Populus I would hate to use and install an entire VM just for testing websites.

Comment: Also, consider using PHP 5.3 :P 5.2 has not been supported since Jan 2011 (http://www.php.net/eol.php)

Comment: @Populus My live server runs PHP 5.0.96, so I need to match it to my local development server.

Comment: Well, if you're going to be testing more than a few websites, a VM is well worth it. To name a couple of advantages: 1) Server environment is more closely matched, 2) It's faster... I'm talking 5-10x faster

Comment: @Populus WAMPServer runs on Windows.

Comment: @RiggsFolly ... ofcourse I know that... Unless you are using WAMP on a live server (you shouldn't...), using WAMP on your development machine is just a convenience and is not a good practice in web development.

Answer (score 0):

The version discrepancy you are seeing sounds like the MySQL *client* software version, not the server version.  Those are two different things.

From a command prompt, I see this:

```
$ echo "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" | php | egrep '^mysqli?$|^Client'

mysql
Client API version => 5.5.32
mysqli
Client API library version => 5.5.32
Client API header version => 5.5.32
Client API version => 5.5.32
```

But the MySQL server itself is 5.5.17.

```
mysql> select @@version;
+------------+
| @@version  |
+------------+
| 5.5.17-log |
+------------+
```